# How to determine the indexes of the leaves in a given subtree in a complete binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree, segment-tree

I have a complete binary tree with 0-based indices:

```
                             0
                 _________ /   \ __________
               /                            \
             1                                2
           /   \                           /     \
         /       \                       /         \
       3           4                   5             6
     /   \       /   \               /   \         /   \
    7     8     9     10           11     12     13     14
```

The indices of the leaf nodes are `7`, `8`, `9`, ..., `14`.

Given a node index `i`, how can we find the indices of the leaf nodes belonging to the subtree whose root node is `i`?

For example,

- When `i == 0`, the answer is `7`, `8`, ..., `14`.
- When `i == 1`, the answer is `7`, `8`, `9` and `10`.
- When `i == 4`, the answer is `9` and `10`.

---

<sub>(↓ Editor's note: The information below is completely irrelevant to the question itself. However, I don't remove it as the information is referred to from the accepted answer.)</sub>

By the way, we assume the nodes have these values (breadth first):

```
[15, 10, 5, 3, 7, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
 ↑                                           ↑
root note                            rightmost leaf node
```

Comment: How does the array depict a tree? What is the logic? How can 19 be an index in this array? How come the leaf at index 8 is both a leaf below node 3 and node 7?

Comment: Sorry for 19, it's 9.

Comment: The zero element (15) is a root, the first (10) and the second (5) are children of the root. The 3rd (3) and the 4th (7) are children of the second element and so on. Thus, leaves are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, their indexes are 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.

Comment: So why is index 8 both a leaf below node 3 and node 7?

Comment: Not my day. I deeply sorry for these mistakes and appreciate you time. Only my bad.

Comment: Next question: so this is about *binary* trees? Is it about *complete* binary trees?

Comment: Yes, definitely. It's always complete binary tree.

Comment: OK, is it even a *perfect* tree always? Or can the bottom level not be completely filled?

Comment: It's always completely filled. Even if it's not filed initially, I would add neutral elements ( zero or infinity). So, all parent  nodes always  have 2 children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the array represents a perfect binary tree, i.e., where all internal nodes have 2 children, and all the leaves are located at the same depth, the array length will always be a power of 2 minus 1. In the example it is 2<sup>4</sup>-1. That power is the number of levels of the tree... which is one more than the tree's height. Let's call the height ℎ, then the size of the input array is 2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>-1.

We can use binary representations of *position* numbers. With position I mean the *index* plus 1. So the root has position 1, and its children have positions 2 and 3. Represent each position in binary representation, using ℎ+1 binary digits. So for the example input, you would use 4 digits. To know the range of positions of the leaves below a given position, see how many leading zeroes there are in the position number.

For instance, take position 3 (where the example tree has value 5), which is 0011 in binary with 4 digits. It has 2 leading zeroes.

Now remove those leading zeroes. For the example we get binary 11.

Now complete these digits *at the right* with any digits to have again 4 digits. This represents the range of positions of the leaves. In the example: 1100 to 1111. You can then turn that back to decimal and subtract 1 to get the indices: 11,12,13,14.

Here is a table that does this calculation for all the internal nodes in your example:

| Index | Value | Position | Position (binary) | Shift | Range | In decimal | Indices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 1 | 0001 | 1*** | 1000-1111 | 8-15 | 7-14 |
| 1 | 10 | 2 | 0010 | 10** | 1000-1011 | 8-11 | 7-10 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 0011 | 11** | 1100-1111 | 12-15 | 11-14 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 0100 | 100* | 1000-1001 | 8,9 | 7,8 |
| 4 | 7 | 5 | 0101 | 101* | 1010-1011 | 10,11 | 9,10 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 | 0110 | 110* | 1100-1101 | 12,13 | 11,12 |
| 6 | 0 | 7 | 0111 | 111* | 1110-1111 | 14,15 | 13,14 |

Comment: That's better than perfect! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

### 0. TL;DR

You can use this, which takes `O(1)` time ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e013344e064957f0ff0c4b9accad2c9c)):

```rust
const n: usize = 8; //the number of leaves

fn depth(i: usize) -> u32 {
    (i + 1).ilog2()
}

fn get_leftmost_leaf_of_subtree(i: usize) -> usize {
    //`(2 * n - 1) - 1` is the index of the rightmost leaf of the entire tree.
    //We choose this index just to calculate the depth of the lowermost layer.
    2usize.pow(depth(2 * n - 1 - 1) - depth(i)) * (i + 1) - 1
}

fn get_rightmost_leaf_of_subtree(i: usize) -> usize {
    2usize.pow(depth(2 * n - 1 - 1) - depth(i)) * (i + 2) - 2
}
```

Let's prove

- the algorithm is correct
- and its time complexity is `O(1)`.

### 1. `O(log(N))` Algorithm

If you use 0-based indices, the indices of the left and right children of the node `i` are `2 * i + 1` and `2 * i + 2` respectively. This calculation takes `O(1)`.

If you start from the node `i` and repeatedly move to the left child of the current node, you will finally reach the leftmost leaf node of the subtree whose root node is `i`.

Similarly, if you repeatedly mode to the right child, you will finally reach the rightmost leaf node of the subtree.

The number of times you need to *go down* is given as `O(log_2(N))` as the current index is doubled every time you go down.

So the time complexity of the algorithm is `O(1) * O(log_2(N)) = O(log(N))`.

### 2. `O(1)` Algorithm

According to the algorithm above, you will repeatedly calculate `2 * i + 1` (or `2 * i + 2`), where `i` is the index of the current node.

This corresponds to this [*nonhomogeneous linear recurrence with a constant coefficient*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients) `a_{n+1} = 2 * a_n + p`, where `p = 1` or `p = 2`. The general term is given as `a_n = 2^n (a_0 + p) - p`.

For example, if you go down `n` times to the left child from the node `i`, the final index is calculated as `a_n = 2^n (i + 1) - 1`, taking `O(1)` time.

And the value of `n` when you repeatedly move down to the leftmost leaf node of the subtree is given by `depth(leaf node) - depth(i)`.

If you (temporarily) use 1-based indices, the *depth* of the node `i` can be calculated as `log_2(i + 1)` in `O(1)`, where the depth of the root node is defined as `0`.

```
                         1  ← depth: 0
             _________ /   \ __________
           /                            \
         2                                3  ← depth: 1
       /   \                           /     \
     /       \                       /         \
   4           5                   6             7  ← depth: 2
 /   \       /   \               /   \         /   \
8     9     10    11           12     13     14     15  ← depth: 3
```

Thus the time complexity of this algorithm is `O(1) * O(1) = O(1)`.